# Mac laptop cannot connect to disk on Mac desktop

Tags: network, smb, file-sharing

I have two Macs, both running Mac OS Sierra. I can ssh from the laptop to the desktop and use Apple's screen sharing to view the desktop's screen from the laptop. I *cannot* mount the desktop's disks on the laptop. I have Sharing turned on, both AFP and SMB, but I cannot connect via either. I've tried connecting to the desktop via smb://, smb://.local, and directly by its local IP address (and the same for afp://). `ssh <hostname>.local` works, so it's not a DNS resolution issue.

The specific error I get is:

> The server may not exist or it is unavailable at this time. Check the server name or IP address, check your network connection, and then try again.

Edit: I should mention that when I try to connect by selecting the machine through the Finder sidebar, it doesn't connect, and clicking "Connect As" fails before getting to the password screen.

Comment: Have you tried sharing with SMB disabled?

Comment: I have not, actually. You're recommending I try just AFP?

Comment: Yah. SMB is for Windows machines to connect to the server.

Comment: In response to your comment to user2720970's answer: are you trying to mount Macintosh HD, or just folders contained within?

Comment: I'm actually trying to mount an attached disk, I was able to do this a few months ago, and I was presented with the options for Macintosh HD and the attached disk.

Comment: @IconDaemon I've turned on AFP and turned off SMB, as well as disabling the firewall and Little Snitch; I get the same error from my original questions.

Comment: Get Info on the attached disk and click the "Ignore ownership on this volume" checkbox. You may need to authenticate with an administrative account by clicking the lock icon. Also: what kind of attached disk? USB, Firewire, Thunderbolt, etc?

Comment: @IconDaemon I figured out my issue, it was a bad configuration on my part. If you would like to put your comments into an answer, I'll upvote them so future people may see them more readily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is my fault; I'd set up File Sharing not only in Sharing preferences like normal, but also in the Server app, and I'd set an access restriction so that only clients with `172.16.*.*` IP addresses could connect and my network is configured as a `192.168.*.*` network.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the user enabled in sharing (File sharing/options)
Then try ssh localusername@hostname.local

Comment: ssh already works; I want to mount the hard drive on my laptop over the network.

Comment: sudo mkdir /Volumes/SHARENAME; sudo mount_afp afp://localusername: localusername@hostname.local/SHARENAME /Volumes/SHARENAME

Comment: I ran `$ sudo mount_afp afp://user@hostname.local/diskName /Volumes/diskName/` and got: 
"mount_afp: AFPMountURL returned error -1069, errno is -1069".

Comment: Thanks for helping, I found out my problem was my own stupid configuration settings. I gave you an upvote as your answer is more likely to be of use to people.